# How to run multiple sites in IIS on Azure

Tags: iis, azure

The Azure VM can run sites locally. How do I make them available to be accessible from outside the VM via browser?

Is it that we add different ports to same ip and access it outside? Public ip is not available to bind, also I know that server has to map endpoints. I have done that .

How to access site that open internally on Different ports *outside* the VM.
What Rules , what firewall settings etc needs to be changed?

Also Why Cant I SEE PUBLIC ip of my VM in IIS binding?

Comment: Do you have problem with your caps lock ?

Comment: Sorry Must have been enabled , i did not notice ... sorry if it annoyed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not see the public ip in IIS binding because you don't have a NIC with an external IP connected to it. The cloud service is the one responsible to bridge your VM (or set of VMs) with the external world and it is also this service which will give you a public IP.

To get your public IP (VIP) just navigate to Cloud Services -> Check ip in quick glance (right side of the dashboard) >> PUBLIC VIRTUAL IP (VIP) ADDRESS

If needed, you can also have more than one VIP:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/

To access your website from the internet, you have to setup the VM endpoints:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/

Make sure Windows Firewall is not blocking the connections as well.

**Update**:

Reserved IP Overview

https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

**Reserving a VIP**

```
New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -Location "East US"
```

Replace MyReservedIP for your desired name. Replace Location with your data center location. To get a list of locations, use Get-AzureLocation

**Associate with your running Cloud Service**

```
Set-AzureReservedIPAssociation -ReservedIPName MyReservedIP -ServiceName TestService
```

Replace MyReservedIP with the one you created and service name with your cloud service name.

**How to install and configure Azure PowerShell**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/

Comment: Thanks for the help i will try this , because now whenever i try to open a website with public ip from internet it points me to default IIS home page , so for that do i have to clear all bindings ?

Also and How do i bind a website in iis , i choose private ip and assign port number or do i just say all unassigned traffic and add port number ?
I have Configured Endpoints from azure portal and also in windows fire wall , went to inbound rules and outbound rules and created a custom rule to allow all local ports , traffic.

Comment: you choose all unassigned and specify the port number. That's all you need to do. If the websites open locally then it should open externally if you opened the correct endpoints. If you are seeing the default IIS homepage it's because everything is working except you either didn't put your website files in the root of your IIS website or it's missing support for php or any other language that is not asp.net.

Comment: thanks sorted that out , but now issue is again if i reboot instance the public ip changes , how to i bind public ip to VM so that it remains same even if i shut down or restart ? Like Elastic Ip in aws so that dns can point to that ip.

Comment: you have to use powershell. first you reserve an ip for your current data center location then you assign this reserved ip to your running cloud service/vm. Here's the doc. https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

Comment: That Documentations is so much confusing sorry i am new , can you type in specific commands that i need to type in powershell to get this done , in simple manner like
do abc this that xyz ,etc 
Where abc has to be name of vm or instance or subscription or ip ,etc 
I need to allocate it to a vm which is currently up and running.

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: It Shows Error "Method Not Found : 'Void Microsoft .WidnowsAzure.Managment.Network.Modles.Network.....(System.String)
At Line:1 Char:1
+Category Info : not Specified : (:) [new-azurereservedip], missing method exception.

Comment: For All Those Who Get This Error ,Update Azure Powershell and Run Command Again it works.